# OutOfMemory Solr 3.4

Tags: java, solr

hi guys sometimes on my website solar goes down, generating an exception.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:435)
```

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

how could I solve it?

Comment: by finding where the problem is and fixing it

Comment: By making more physical memory available to the JVM or using less.

Comment: Also, you should investigate with a profiler if there are any resource leak in your application.

Comment: Try running Solr with the `-Xmx` option increased compared to the default value (you probably want `-Xms` to equal the Xmx value as well in your particular case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try to apply newer version of Solr, it may handle memory better than older versions.
2. Try to change GC algorithms (such as CMS, G1..) and monitor it.
3. Start with flag `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. Analyze the heapdump with visualvm, jmap ... to detect any memory leak issues.
4. Incr -Xmx as much as you can